No puedo usar la terminal en visual studio code
El texto que me figura es

the terminal process 'program files\git\bin\bash.exe--login,'.


Terminated with exit code 1.


estás trabajando en linux o por que seleccionaste bash?

@RuslanLópez Bash le da 100 vueltas a la consola de windows para trabajar. Especialmente si estás acostumbrado a los comandos de linux. Vamos, yo trabajo en windows y también uso siempre el bash que te instala git en VSC! No es nada raro

@Benito-B es raro porque la selección por defecto es powershell... y con base en el mensaje de error se me ocurre que el op instaló bash, lo seleccionó en vscode como terminal por defecto y después desinstaló bash

@RuslanLópez powershell tampoco me gusta :) Si te fijas en la ruta, está haciendo lo mismo que yo, está usando bash a través de git 'program files\git\bin\bash.exe. Más bien parece algún problema causado por el parámetro --login que le está poniendo ahí tan pegado. Beleen, puedes dar un poco más de contexto?? "No puedo usarla" es muy poca información. Qué exactamente has hecho para ver ese mensaje?? Cómo has configurado el bash? Como dice Ruslan, no es la opción por defecto, cómo lo cambiaste? Necesitamos verlo todo, o es imposible saber qué pasa
